# Automatically creating symlimks for files

Tags: linux, shell, unix, debian, symlink

I am in a rather unique predicament.

Let's say that I am on a Linux-based computer. It could be anything, really. The important part is that I have **2** partitions on my device. 1 that is around **1 GB** and another that is around **15 GB**.

The 1 GB partition (mounted on /) is reserved for system use, and the rest (mounted on /home) is for the user (me) to use.

Suppose I am running low on free space in my system partition. However, I want to install some command line utilities (which, of course, install to the system).

In the meantime, I create a folder in `/home` called `stash`. More on this later.

So, I download a tool, for example, bash. Bash is a .deb which I end up extracting to `/home/stash`. Let's assume bash is too big for me to install it to the system. That's okay, I can just create a symlimk at /bin/bash that redirects to `/home/stash/bin/bash`.

However, I'd like not only to symlink `/bin/bash`, but all of the other directories in the `/home/stash` folder. Is there a way that I could automate this symlink process?

Comment: Yes there is a way, you can use bash, Ansible, python, etc to do what you are asking.

Comment: Possible solution [from superuser](http://superuser.com/q/356804/14566): `cp -rs source/ dest/`